# Right Click on bing map exactly on Circle using selenium driver

Tags: javascript, selenium, bing-maps

I want to perform right click on bing map circle using selenium Driver

[image]

I want to get street view of correct latitude and longitude which i am entering to search bar but unfortunately when i perform right click
using below code, the right click is performed left side of the circle which is not correct location. I am wondering if someone there help me to get rid of this bug.

```
driver.actions().click(driver.findElement(By.css('#labelCanvasId')),button.RIGHT).perform();
```

I have highlighted the area where most the time right click operation is performed which in turn obviously taking to wrong street view for the latitude longitude.

Comment: @James Z any help in this regard ?

Comment: Write a clear question with a good title and include what you have tried so far.

Comment: Writing code against the Bing Maps consumer website is against the terms of use. If you want to do development with Bing Maps, use the developer API's: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd877180.aspx